# How to archive data in Lotus Domino DB and keep attachments stored in DAOS

Tags: lotus-domino, archiving

I logged the [following question](https://serverfault.com/questions/419846/daos-estimator-run-on-large-lotus-notes-database#comment446626_419846) in server fault, and it was suggested I log a dev question related to that question, so here it is.

I have a Lotus Domino DB being archived using the LS method CopyToDatabase.  I am about to implement DAOS on the database and need to ensure that attachments are preseved when copied to the archive.

The person who answered the first question suggested that this would not work and that I would lose the attachments.  Can anyone advise how to code the archiving (I can only think of using CopyToDatabase) to ensure that the attachment is not lost?

I had assumed Domino would:

- move the attachment data from DOAS into Domino when the CopyToDatabase was run.
- then move the attachment data back into DOAS if the DB it is copied to also has DAOS enabled.

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really is an admin question, but the reasoning does involve understanding things from a developer's perspective, so it's pretty reasonable to ask here.

DAOS is 100% invisible to Notes code at all levels.  It doesn't matter whether it is LotusScript, Java, or the Notes C API.  The code is 100% unaware of DAOS.  You actually cannot write special code that deals directly with DAOS objects.

So, your assumption is basically correct.  You just didn't mention the actual part where the attachment is deleted, and a couple of other miscellaneous details.

I.e.,  if the archive database that you are copying to exists on the same server as the source database, and both are enabled for DAOS, then the attachment will remain in DAOS even after you delete it from the source database.

But if the archive database that you are copying to is on a different server, or if it is on a users's local hard drive, and if the attachment does not also exist in some other DAOS-enabled database on the server, then the attachment will be removed from DAOS.  This will occur at the next DAOS purge after the time that you delete the document (or just the attachment) from the source database.

Comment: Thanks @rhsatrhs.  That was my understanding of DAOS, and I kinda suspected that the CopyToDatabase method would keep the attachment in DAOS if both DB's were DAOS enabled.  Appreciate the clarification.